# Find all elements of the set $ \{ \sigma \in S_6 : \sigma(12)(34)\sigma^{-1}=(12)(34)\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Find all elements of the set $ \{ \sigma \in S_6 : \sigma(12)(34)\sigma^{-1}=(12)(34)\}$

I have read that two permutations conjugate if they have the same cycle type. So we have a cycle type of $(1,1,2,2)$ Now is their a particular algorithm to find all these quickly? I belive their should be $16$ of them given $6\choose 2$$=15$.

Comment: Clearly $(56)$ and $(65)$ are two possible elements $\sigma$. We know this since disjoint elements commute and $\sigma$ cancels with its inverse.

Comment: I am more curious if there is a general algorithm for any permutation.

Comment: In fact all $(1,5),(1,6),(2,5),(2,6),(3,5),(3,6),(4,5),(4,6),(5,6),(6,5)$ will work. As would the identity $()$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\sigma(12)(34)\sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(1),\sigma(2))(\sigma(3),\sigma(4))$.

And the size of this set is
\begin{equation*}
\frac{|S_6|}{\text{number of elements of this cycle type}} = \frac{6!}{{6\choose 2}{4\choose 2}/2} = 16.
\end{equation*}